# sharing dependecy injection between windows service and its self hosted web api

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, self-hosting

I am building a c# Windows Service, and I have added a self hosted Web API.
Im using the ServiceCollection as DI solution for the Windows Service, this is working fine.

How do i use the same ServiceCollection for the Web API, so that both the Windows Service and Web API can resolve the same service (IMyAwsomeManager)?

The HTTPConfiguration has the DependencyResolver property, but that takes a IDependencyResolver, which IServiceCollection is not.

Do I have to use another DI solution than ServiceCollection to get this working? (Autofac or something)

Comment: What IoC container are you using in the Windows Service project? If you're not sure, the fully-qualified type name of `ServiceCollection` may give some clues.

Comment: Im using the builtin Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection as IoC container for the windows service, that is the one im trying to share to the Web API. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?